# EasyMotion coloring in vim with Solarized theme?

Tags: vim, themes

I'm using the [Solarized](http://ethanschoonover.com/solarized) theme for vim (which is amazing), but the color defaults for [EasyMotion](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3526) are, well, downright unreadable.

When I activate EasyMotion, the leader letters are clearly visible (bright red, with Solarized Dark), but the words they key to are barely a shade different from the background (dark blue against slightly darker blue background).

How can I change this to be more readable?

---

SOLUTION: Edit your .vimrc file like so:

```
" change the default EasyMotion shading to something more readable with Solarized
hi link EasyMotionTarget ErrorMsg
hi link EasyMotionShade  Comment
```

A la section 4.5 in the docs for the plugin.

Comment: Do you know how to change the actual color of the text when using easymotion as the /character search? In the readme it shows him using the n character search and every letter typed after / is highlighted bright green. I got the shade to comment which is the same but I don't know how to change the text color itself as being typed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The author of EasyMotion has written excellent documentation on what is possible with EasyMotion.  The helptags that stand out to me are `EasyMotion_do_shade` and `easymotion-custom-hl`.  These define whether or not to highlight the shaded text and how to hilight the shaded and target text.

Comment: Ahh, I just didn't peruse the docs thoroughly enough. However, the actual configuration options specific to my question are posted in the update above. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I tend to use the same highlighting as when searching.

There are also two more settings available, refering to the source code (https://github.com/Lokaltog/vim-easymotion/blob/master/t/easymotion_spec.vim#L507) :

```
" easymotion highlight colors
hi link EasyMotionTarget Search
hi link EasyMotionTarget2First Search
hi link EasyMotionTarget2Second Search
hi link EasyMotionShade Comment
```